# Change background color of UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I would like to change the color behind the flip from white to a different color or picture. Is that possible?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change the background colour of the UIWindow in MainWindow.nib. Either "black" or "clear" should both work (I think...)

It's one of the first things I do to any app, otherwise you get bits of white showing on a view rotation (in the very old days of 2.x there were huge patches of white; they've since masked off the screen edges during a rotation, but a few pixels still show through) and when you show/hide the status bar (e.g. for UIImagePicker) and stuff. Black looks a *lot* better than white for the window background.

Comment: Thanks! Had to read it twice to realize that you were talking about the MainWindow.xib, not the "main window" that is displayed when you launch the app.

Comment: window.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];